# GDB prints incorrect parameter value in kernel

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb, kernel

I'm debugging Linux kernel with gdb, the breakpoint works fine.

But when gdb breaks, the passed in parameter value were incorrect.

```
Breakpoint 4, XXX (a=0xb008, b=1, c=1, d=0x0, e=0) at XX.c:YY
```

Yes, all these values are wrong. I added a few printk in the XXX kernel function, and confirmed it was wrong. (It wasn't a data format problem)

I have tested with `gcc-4.6 and gcc-4.9` same result. I didn't modify `CFLAGS_KERNEL` either.

Perhaps a gdb problem? I'm using version `7.7.1`

P.S I have also tried with multiple kernel source code, 3.12.8, 3.4.0 2.6.32 etc. No change.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information here to know what the problem is.  It might be a gdb problem, though from the description I would say it is more likely a debug info issue.  But there is no easy way to tell, one must dive into the debug info, the assembly emitted by the compiler, and the gdb source code in order to decide where the bug lies.